# How can I remove \n's and \t's from a Python string in order to parse JSON?

Tags: python, string, json, unicode

Python thinks I have the following text:

```
"[\n\t{\n\t\t\"my_key\": 3}]"
```

However, I want it to think this is JSON, so that I can load it with `simplejson.dumps()`.

What is the Python way to parse / remove `\n` and `\t` from a string so that I can parse it as JSON?

Comment: Don't you want to `loads` it instead of `dumps`?

Comment: Where are you getting this string from that your escape characters are coming in escaped.

Comment: @Falmarri I assume he's showing the `repr()` of the string so that there is no ambiguity about its contents.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to load, why are you using dump?

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("[\n\t{\n\t\t\"my_key\": 3}]")
[{u'my_key': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Python's replace method. Replace these items with a empty string and they will be gone.  Be careful you don't chew up newlines you need.